# return type of virtual function 'method' is not covariant with the return type of the function it overrides c++

Tags: c++

**BreadthSearchableContainer.hpp**

```
template <typename Data>
class BreadthSearchableContainer{

public:

  virtual ~BreadthSearchableContainer() = default;

  BreadthSearchableContainer& operator=(const BreadthSearchableContainer&) = delete;

  BreadthSearchableContainer& operator=(BreadthSearchableContainer&&) noexcept = delete;

  bool operator==(const BreadthSearchableContainer&) const noexcept = delete;
  bool operator!=(const BreadthSearchableContainer&) const noexcept = delete;

  using typename SearchableContainer<Data>::MapFunctor;
  virtual void MapBreadth(MapFunctor, void*) = 0;

  using typename SearchableContainer<Data>::FoldFunctor;
  virtual void FoldBreadth(FoldFunctor, const void*, void*) const = 0;

   };
```

**binarytree.hpp**

```
  template <typename Data>
  class BinaryTree : virtual public BreadthSearchableContainer<Data>{

   public:

    struct Node {

     public:

      friend class BinaryTree<Data>;
      virtual Node& LeftChild() = 0;
    };
  };
```

**binarytreelnk.hpp**

```
  template <typename Data>
  class BinaryTreeLnk : public BinaryTree<Data>{

    public:

      struct NodeLnk : public BinaryTree<Data>::Node{

        protected:

          Data Elements;
          struct NodeLnk* left_child;
          struct NodeLnk* right_child;

        public:

          friend class BinaryTreeLnk<Data>;

          NodeLnk& LeftChild() override; 

      };
      protected:

        struct NodeLnk* Nodelnk_root;  
   };
```

**binarytreelnk.cpp**

```
template<typename Data>
typename BinaryTreeLnk<Data>::NodeLnk& BinaryTreeLnk<Data>::NodeLnk::LeftChild(){
  if(left_child == nullptr){
    throw std::out_of_range("Figlio sinisto non esistente");
  }
  else{
    return Node(left_child);
  }
}
```

**MAIN**

```
void main(){

 BinaryTreeLnk<int> binary;

}
```

**ERROR**

```
binarytreelnk.hpp:58:14: error: return type of virtual function 'LeftChild' is not covariant
      with the return type of the function it overrides ('lasd::BinaryTreeLnk<int>::NodeLnk &' is not derived from
      'lasd::BinaryTree<int>::Node &')
    NodeLnk& LeftChild() override;
    ~~~~~~~~ ^
binarytree.hpp:55:19: note: overridden virtual function is here
    virtual Node& LeftChild() = 0;
```

I tell you right now that the project I’m doing is really huge and I don’t know if I was able to compress the necessary code to understand the error. However, this error could also concern compiler problems since to other colleagues of mine such a thing does not come out even with the code perfectly equal to mine. I have avoided putting includes as I know for certain that they have been inserted perfectly. If you can tell me why this mistake I would be very grateful. thanks in advance

Comment: You have an undefined base class `virtual public BreadthSearchableContainer`. Once I add an empty one, I cannot reproduce your error. Please post [mcve], make sure there is a single file that can be copied and pasted to an online compiler.https://godbolt.org/z/qY_5iK

Comment: unfortunately the Breadthsearchablecontainer class is in turn extended by another and yet another however within the same there are all virtual methods not implemented and that have nothing to do with the leftchild method

Comment: @MicheleAmbrosanio: Please provide a _minimal_ example. There's way too much code here, including a namespace that's almost certainly unnecessary.

Comment: This [still does not show any problem](https://godbolt.org/z/Tk9amW) except failure to include parts required to compile your code. Oh, and `void main()`. `main` is not allowed to return `void`. Please paste **the exact same code you post here** to an online compiler and verify compilation results.